# Javascript - Cleaner way to set object field & values than using forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, foreach

I currently have something like this:

```
queryElastic().then(res => {
  const map = {};
  res.hits.hits.forEach(el => {
    map [el._source.key] = el._source.value;
  });
  this.setState({
    map : map 
  })
}
```

Is there a cleaner/more concise approach to set the map object? I am thinking of array.map but this doesnt help me too much because it returns an array, and I need to set all the key/value pairs within an object.

On an unrelated note, is there a simple way to reverse all the key/value pairs of a flat object? Basically I want my values to become keys, and keys to become values.

Current I am doing it a dumb way:

```
  const map = {};
  const mapInverse = {};
  res.hits.hits.forEach(el => {
    map[el._source.key] = el._source.value;
    mapInverse[el._source.value] = el._source.key;
  })
```

Thanks in advance all.

Answer (score 3):

Your way to create your map looks pretty clean already, although generally I think `for` loops are better for simpler cases.

This is how I might write this:

```js
const res = await queryElastic();
const map = {};
for (const {_source: {key, value}} of res.hits) {
  map[key] = value;
}
this.setState({
  map,
})
```

You could also do it like this:

```js
const map = Object.fromEntries(
   res.hits.map(({_source: {key, value}}) => [key, value])
);
```

But fewer lines doesn't make it more readable necessarily. Do you understand just by glancing at this what this does? Do other team members do? More lines *can* be good if the intent is clearer.

Comment: Particularly like your comment that shorter is not necessarily better if it's not as clear or obvious what it does or how it works.  This needs to be taught more often.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The standard for look and manually settings each map[key] pair seems to be most readable. The shorter ones are actually less readable!

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `reduce` method and object destructuring, it makes things quite neat and readable imo:

```
const map = res.hits.hits.reduce((acc, {_source: {key, value}}) => (
  {...acc, [key]: value}
), {});
```

It also makes it trivial to modify to do things in the "reverse" way as you ask - just change the `[key]: value` to `[value]: key`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this improves the readability, but you could tighten it up and eliminate the pre-declared variables using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for the first bit:

```js
queryElastic().then(res => {
  const map = res.hits.hits.reduce((acc, ({ _source: { key, value }})) => ({
    ...acc, [key]: value
  }), {});

  this.setState({
    map : map 
  })
}
```

And you could use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to reverse the keys and values:

```js
const reversed = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(someObject)
    .map(([key, value]) => [value, key])
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking of arr.reduce() but it seems it doesnt improve the readability!